# Add QT window to chrome browser window

Tags: qt, winapi

my code as follows：

```
         HWND hwnd = (HWND)FindWindow(L"Notepad", NULL);//Chrome_WidgetWin_1  Notepad
         SetWindowPos(  (HWND)w.winId(),HWND_TOPMOST  ,200,200,200,232,SWP_NOSIZE|SWP_SHOWWINDOW );
          SetParent((HWND) w.winId(),hwnd);
```

I add qt window to Notepad is ok，but add QT window to chrome browser window is failed，the qt code is quickly disappear

Comment: [Is it legal to have a cross-process parent/child or owner/owned window relationship?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683) Key insight: *"You must first become the master of the rules before you can start breaking them."*

Comment: I have add the qt window to chrome，but the chrome not show the qt window，it can deal qt event。By spy++，my qt window is child of chrome。 why the chrome not show my qt window

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? There might be a better way to achieve your goal.

Answer (score -1):

Consider that QT interface has its own coordinate system mechanism

Comment: is it .dll? or .exe ?  or  .ocx?  Chrome doesn't support self written extensions since 3.5

Comment: it is a exe，i have add the window to the chrome，the spy++ can see it，it is chrome child，but the chrome not show it。

Comment: The window isn't showing because **neither** process is prepared to create a cross-thread window hierarchy. The coordinate system isn't related at all.

Comment: @IInspectable as the link describe https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/50253-Embed-Qt-Widgets-in-a-browser?highlight=Embedded+chrome  , the setparent can finish i want

Comment: @pen Of course, it is *"technically"* possible, as explained in the link I posted in a comment to your question. But you **absolutely** have to know what you're doing, and **everyone** has to be prepared for it. Clearly, one of those applications is outside your control, and your understanding of the technical concepts are easily a decade behind what is minimally required.

Comment: @IInspectable can you help me ，give some clue to show it by Qt

Comment: I cannot teach you windowing in ten minutes. You're going to have to educate yourself. Start by ditching Qt altogether, and use the native windowing API exclusively. That's still not going to work reliably, since your target process is not under your control. But at least you'll learn how things work.